# Ctrl+F and Ctrl+H doesn't work in SQL management studio

Tags: ssms

I cannot use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in my *SQL Management studio*. Even if I use the menu items it doesn't work. Haven't installed anything new or changed anything recently. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your keyboard plugged in? Sounds silly, but you wouldn't believe the number of times my foot-whirling has knocked loose a cable or two. I think my app has gone nuts until I realise nothing else works either!

Comment: He's able to type in StackOverflow though

Comment: @ButterChicken, I may be FailBoy but certainly not StupidBoy. lol!

@Patrick, We share a surname so you rock ;)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Have you recently used multi-monitor? Is it possible that it is opening off-screen? I get this problem a lot when disconnecting my laptop from an external monitor...

(edit) There is a Window -> Reset Window Layout menu option in SSMS 2008, that should fix it.

Comment: Dude you are a champion of note! Thanks a million mate!

Comment: I have a single monitor, and yet it's been happening recently. Saved my sanity, thanks!

Comment: Thank You!!!! . Was so frustrated with this. It took me 15 min to decide to get on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect! multi-monitor causes this.. Just minimize VS. Put to the other monitor.
You'll see opened window when you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Irina

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this issue also, I am using two monitors but this appears not to be the cause. I say this as the instance of management studio that I have open has two queries - both are connected to the same Server and Instance. On one query, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works fine, on the other query it won't work at all.

I think this is in some way related to debugging - the query which does not allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> currently I mistakenly debugged (as opposed to running) and after this the find/find replace functionality does not work!